# Change axes after plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

After having plotted some data:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(np.linspace(-3.0, 3.0, 10), np.random.random(10))
plt.plot(np.linspace(0.0, 7.0, 50),  np.random.random(50))
plt.show()
```

[image]

I'd like to change the x-axis labels to 0.0 ... 50.0 instead of -4.0 ... 8.0 (but keeping exactly the same plot).
**Is it possible to do it in one-line?**

Comment: What exactly do you mean in one-line ? Without an additional one to your code ?

Comment: @Moritz : I'd like to change the axis' label to 0.0 ... 50.0     like this : http://gget.it/hodulb9e/EovWW.png

Comment: I suggest you scale your data like `data - min(data)` and do `plt.xlim(0,50)`

Comment: But that would be at least two lines

Comment: I would like to do it without modifying data, but just faking the x-axis label

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the following function](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks), and give numerical labels:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(np.linspace(-3.0, 3.0, 10), np.random.random(10))
plt.plot(np.linspace(0.0, 7.0, 50), np.random.random(50))

plt.xticks([-4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8], ['0', '10', '20', '30', '40', '50'])
```

Comment: I understand that this is what the OP requested, but this isn't really a great solution in general, since you've decoupled the tick labels from the data coordinates

Comment: Sure, this is making the graph to lie about its content. But if one doesn't have a way to change the generation of the lines but only the figure generation, it may be useful.